# Concatenação de String em PHP a partir de Array

Tags: php

Tenho uma consulta ao meu banco de dados que retornar para mim um array cada linha do banco é um array,

```
$qr = DBRead('sales', "WHERE status = 1");
foreach ($qr as $position => $linha){
    $vendas = $linha['cod_produto'];

    var_dump($vendas); 
}
```

Isso imprimi para o sequinte array

```
array (size=25)
    'venda' => string '96' (length=2)
    'cod_produto' => string '1; 2; 8' (length=7)

array (size=25)
    'venda' => string '98' (length=2)
    'cod_produto' => string '; 1; 2; 8' (length=9)
```

E assim por diante, quanto mais registro mais arrays.

Minha pergunta é quero pega a chave `cod_produto` e seleciona seu valor e colocar em uma única string com todos esses valores concatenados alguém tem uma ideia de como fazer isso com php?

Comment: Utilize a função join ou implode. Fica mais simples e elegante. função join: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.join.php
função implode: https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.implode.php

Answer (score 0):

Para concatenar string em php você deve usar `$vartexto = $vartexto . 'texto novo';` ou de forma reduzida `$vartexto.='texto novo';`

Segue o seu trecho de código com uma variável `$cod_produtos_juntos` que fará essa concatenação pra você:

```
$qr = DBRead('sales', "WHERE status = 1");

$cod_produtos_juntos = '';
foreach ($qr as $position => $linha)
{
    $cod_produtos_juntos.=$linha['cod_produto'];
}

echo $cod_produtos_juntos;
```

Comment: O que ficou confuso para mim é que ele atribuiu à `$vendas$` o valor de `$linha['cod_produto']` e quando deu o `var_dump`, `$vendas` possui novamente o índice `cod_produto`. Pela lógica apresentada seria `$cod_produtos_juntos .= $vendas['cod_produto']`. Embora acredito que ele se confundiu no resultado mesmo.

Comment: O que vc falou faz todo sentido Anderson.

Comment: Se $vendas['cod_produto'] for um array com venda e cod_produto, então pra pegar só cod_produto teria q ser $cod_produtos_juntos.=$linha['cod_produto']['cod_produto']; mas acredito que o Joao tenha dado var_dump em $linha puro antes.

Comment: Antonio, se quiser adicionar a sua resposta para não haver necessidade de criar outra: https://repl.it/F6BG/0. Assim dá para ver a diferença em funcionamento.

Comment: Não consegui abrir o seu link. Trava meu Firefox. :/